# How to fix font black stroke/outline?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have the header, which gets white background on a scroll and when it's on the top of the page is transparent. The problem is that when I scroll down and the background gets white after I reach the top of the page and the background becomes transparent my navigation gets some black outline. I figure out that somehow the problem comes because of the background color when I scroll down but I don't know how to fix this issue, I need that background. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xC0Fj.png)

```
.header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    z-index: 10;
    border-bottom: 1px solid @white;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out, transform .3s ease-in-out;
a {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-family: 'UniNeue-Regular', sans-serif;
    color: @white;[enter image description here][1]
}

&.sticky{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: @white;
    transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out, transform .3s ease-in-out;
    border-bottom: 1px solid @black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
a {webkit-text-stroke-width: 0;}
```

or

```
 a {text-shadow: unset;}
```